# Can I use include and redirect in same SPF record?

Tags: spf, txt-record

My current SPF record is as below

```
Host                  Value                                   TTL
myexampledomain.com   "v=spf1 redirect=_spf.mailhostbox.com" 1 Day
```

I am using 2 free email offered by the hosting provider. Now I have got a VPS where I have created email server. The thing is I want to create new email addresses for my domain and add a proper SPF and DKIM record.

I tried to use include:myexampledomain.com mx a in the SPF record, but then everything stopped working, even the 2 free emails.

Is it right to use include as well as redirect in same SPF record?
Or would like to know what should be the right way to do this? I do not want my email should land up in spam / junk mails. Also, if this is impossible is it possible to use Gmail to Send Email as mynewemail@myexampledomain.com?

I am quite confused, read many articles but was not able to get the answer.
Other settings are as below
**MX records**

```
Priority    Host                MX Entry                    TTL
100     myexampledomain.com.    us2.mx3.mailhostbox.com.    1 day
100     myexampledomain.com.    us2.mx1.mailhostbox.com.    1 day
100     myexampledomain.com.    us2.mx2.mailhostbox.com.    1 day
```

**CNAME records**

```
Alias Host                      Canonical Host                  TTL
webmail.myexampledomain.com.    us2.webmail.mailhostbox.com.    1 day
smtp.myexampledomain.com.       us2.smtp.mailhostbox.com.       1 day
imap.myexampledomain.com.       us2.imap.mailhostbox.com.       1 day
pop.myexampledomain.com.        us2.pop.mailhostbox.com.        1 day
```

Comment: For troubleshooting DNS records, it is most useful if you provide the actual domains. It is unlikely you will get a resolution to your issue from this community without such information.

Answer (score 3):

Per [RFC 7208](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-6.1):

You can use any mechanism with `redirect` **except for the `all` mechanism**.

Note that it doesn't make much sense to use `redirect` unless you are redirecting to records for a domain that is also under your control. If a third party asks you to do this, beat them over the head with a copy of the RFC; they should generally be asking you to `include` instead.

Comment: + make sure you `include` before you `redirect`